# Realtime encoding `MediaRecorder` stream to `mp3`

Tags: javascript, mp3, web-worker, web-mediarecorder, lamemp3

I want to realtime encode `MediaRecorder` stream to `mp3`.

Currently I am saving stream from `MediaRecorder` as a blob variable. After the recording is done, I am converting the blob to `wav` and after that I am using [lamejs](https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs) to encode it to MP3. Because this process is on the main thread, encoding 5 minute long recording freezes the browser.

After searching online I found https://aws.nlited.org/mp3.htm, which is what I need. Unfortunately i throws a warning/error `The ScriptProcessorNode is deprecated. Use AudioWorkletNode instead.` in the console.

I also tried

```
const dataArray = []

// globally load lamejs
const mp3Encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(
  1,
  44000,
  128
)

const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
  audioBitsPerSecond: 9000,
})

recorder.ondataavailable = async ({ data }) => {
  const mp3Data = mp3Encoder.encodeBuffer(data) // I am not able to encode the data here, because the types/values does not match/do not work

  dataArray.push(mp3Data)
}

recorder.onstop = async () => {
  mediaStream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())

  const mp3Data = mp3Encoder.flush()
  dataArray.push(mp3Data)
}

// ----
// on play
// const blob = new Blob(dataArray, { type: 'audio/mp3' })
// download blob
```

I do not want to use webworker right now (or if you have drop-in replacement, feel free to help) or the `ffmpeg` library (too big for this use-case)

Maybe related - https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs/issues/68? But without an answer

Is there a way, how achieve the goal I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> After searching online I found https://aws.nlited.org/mp3.htm, which is what I need. Unfortunately i throws a warning/error The ScriptProcessorNode is deprecated. Use AudioWorkletNode instead. in the console.

Yeah, well, you can ignore that error.  It's been deprecated for years as a matter of best practice, but I don't really see anyone removing ScriptProcessorNode anytime soon.

In any case, *most* code that works in ScriptProcessorNode can be easily adapted to work with [AudioWorklet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorklet), which is intended to replace ScriptProcessorNode and runs on a different thread.

> I do not want to use webworker right now (or if you have drop-in replacement, feel free to help) or the ffmpeg library (too big for this use-case)

That's unfortunate, because that is the solution to your problem.  You could build FFmpeg with Emscripten with just the modules you need for your use case and cut its size down considerably.